# How to get two tuples - one with words and another with its length?

Tags: python

I have a string "I am a fool"
I want a tuple returned that has the word and its length:

```
[("I", 1), ("am", 2), ("a", 1), ("fool", 4)]
```

I can convert the string to a list and get the length of each word but can't combine the two to get the above.

The above is definitely not the right way to approach the problem as I get two separate lists where as I want the above tuple.

Comment: It is always good to show any code that you have written. You are probably being downvoted because of this. Try adding the code that you have already written. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following.

```
input = "I am a fool"
[(x,len(x)) for x in input.split(" ")]
```

It splits the string on spaces and converts it to a list though.

Answer (score 1):

i use a dictionary instead of tuples  , hope it helps you

```
#%%
def function():
    str_="I am a fool"
    str_split=str_.split()
    dict={}
    for x in range(len(str_split)):
        dict[str_split[x]]=len(str_split[x])
    for x, y in dict.items():
        print(x, y)
```

Comment: Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.